# Using the color aesthetic with geom_tile in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, ggplotly

I'm attempting to make a geom_tile plot to use in a shiny dashboard. I have created the plot in ggplot2 and it works perfectly. However when I attempt to plot using ggplotly the border around the tiles do not show up.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3L), 
                 y = rep(letters[1:3], 3L), 
                 fill = rnorm(9L))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y,fill=fill)) + geom_tile(size = 2, color="black")
p
ggplotly(p)
```

I am using R version 3.6.0, ggplot2 3.1.1, plotly version 4.9.0

Comment: As documented by [this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/898) issue, this feature is not currently supported by plotly.